# How can draw a graph by networkx by giving the edges order to draw?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to plot a graph by networkx by edges order. In my data set there are many transport alternative but since the buses are dominant the are means can not be seen. How can I plot order edges on top of the buses?

```
colors_p = nx.get_edge_attributes(net_p, 'color').values()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
nx.draw_networkx(net_p, ax=ax2,pos=nx.get_node_attributes(net_p, 'pos'), with_labels=False, node_size=0.5,
                     alpha=0.5, node_color = 'black', edge_color = colors_p)


ax2.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax2.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
proxies = [make_proxy(clr, lw=5) for clr in edge_types.keys()]
labels = [edge_type for clr, edge_type in edge_types.items()]
ax2.set_title('pspace')
plt.legend(proxies, labels);
```

[image]

Comment: You can draw nodes and edges separately with `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` and `nx.draw_networkx_edges`. You can draw edges of different classes in any preferred order.

Comment: Can you explain your answer with an example?

Comment: Instead of calling `nx.draw_networkx`, extract, say, the "rail" edges, plot them with `nx.draw_networkx_edges`. Then extract the "tram" edges and again plot them with `nx.draw_networkx_edges`. Eventually, plot the "bus" edges with the same function - they will be on top of everything else. Finally, draw the nodes with  `nx.draw_networkx_nodes`.

Comment: Now that I'm back at my desktop, I'll post the comment as an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `nx.draw_networkx()` that draws the graph the way it finds suitable, you can draw the chart element-wise.

Start by extracting a subset of edges (say, the "rail" edges) and plotting them with `nx.draw_networkx_edges()`. Then extract the "tram" edges and again plot them with `nx.draw_networkx_edges()`. Eventually, plot the "bus" edges with the same function - they will be on top of everything else.

Finally, draw the nodes with `nx.draw_networkx_nodes()`.